# Routing In Angular6

Tags: angular, routes, angular6

I have application that have a navigation bar and in the navigation bar i have contactUs component.
i can open the navigation bar from any of my componenets, and to go to contactUs component.
in the contactUs  component i have a back button and i want to be able to take the user back from any component he opend the contactUs .
how can i achieve this?

i tried using routerLink on the button, and a navigatebyUrl with the router module but i only can take the user back from a specific url, like "/home"
and i want it to be changes depends on the user location,
e.g

if user is open the 
About > contactUs (so contactUs back button take back to About Component)
Home > contactUs (so contactUs back button take back to Home Component)

How can i achieve this approch?

Comment: It's exactly like you mentioned using routerLink to navigate to a specif  component, where are you struggling with that solution? Give us your source where exactly you tried implement it and it didn't work.

Comment: But i dont know to what component to take him, its depends on the Component he opend it from like the example i gave above, is there any "stack navigation" so i can take the user just one back route?

Comment: But you actually know from which component you click on the about button, you can send the route url via parameter to the about button.

Comment: Without more details, there are some different solutions.
<br>Try the followings:<br>
https://blog.hackages.io/our-solution-to-get-a-previous-route-with-angular-5-601c16621cf0<br>
Its usefull is you want to use your own 'router service' https://www.bennadel.com/blog/3533-using-router-events-to-detect-back-and-forward-browser-navigation-in-angular-7-0-4.htm
<br>
Doc here: https://angular.io/api/router/NavigationStart

Comment: I have a feeling you embedded that navbar component, separately, within each and every component. if that is the case you're doing it wrong, that navbar should only be embedded once. at a parent component.

Comment: @Stavm No, i embedded it above the <router-outlet></router-outlet> in the app.component.html file used this blog to achieve this approch: https://blog.hackages.io/our-solution-to-get-a-previous-route-with-angular-5-601c16621cf0

Answer (score 0):

You need to give specific code or name to each component. When clicking on it you can store it so ewhere like in globat variable or local storage. For example if you click on contact button from about us page then store about us page from route so ewhere. Now once you are on contact page, and when you click back button then you can find out last saved value in the local storage and redirect to that page.